# HTML5 elments categories terminology

Tags: html

In HTML5 no longer exists the distinction between inline, block and replaced elements but there are other categories like: flow, phrasing, etc. that sometimes overlaps.

So how can I know if one HTML5 elements is inline, block or replaced?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your CSS, which element is styled as what. Each browser vendor includes a default stylesheet which can be overridden by several other stylesheets. Try to find browser default CSS to get an overview on which elements are styled as block elements.